# Firebase error handling

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried performing relatively simple tasks, e.g:

```
router.get('/api/getOne:id', (req,res) => {
   db.child(req.params.id.substr(1)).remove();
}
```

But from the official documentation I can't seem to figure out if they have implemented callbacks for error handling. In the above example, I want to capture if the supplied `id` doesn't exist in the database.

I can implement this myself, but thought I'd ask the question if this is something that exists natively.

Comment: Did you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458685/how-does-or-how-can-you-effectively-handle-errors-using-firebase

Comment: Thanks @israel.zinc - No somehow I missed that one! Thanks for bringing to my attention, that answers my question.

Comment: I will post as a answer then, and you can accept it :p